# jdbc statement fetch size in DB2

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

Im trying to set fetchSize on statment, while executing query so that can improve performance of some long running query. My DB2 jdbc driver version is 3.64 (DB2 version 9.2). But im not seeing any difference in total execution time even with a higher fetch size. By default if I try to invoke `statement.getFetchSize()`, before executing query its returning 0. This [link](http://webmoli.com/2009/02/01/jdbc-performance-tuning-with-optimal-fetch-size/) was mentioning that DB2 default fetch size is 32. Is there any different configuration (along with opening connection, like setting up some specific properties etc.) I need to setup to enable varying fetch size with DB2? Or is it that DB2 jdbc driver does not support varying fetch size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can control the fetch size on DB2 , but first you need to set `enableRowsetSupport` for your jdbc driver. See more [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.java.doc/doc/rjvdsprp.htm).